Married man and salesman have very pleasant conversation after marital argument
I've been looking for this movie for a long time.
I watched the movie with Turkish dubbing in 2005-2007. This must be a TV movie. Might be an American film, I don't know. The film takes place in one room.
A married couple have an argument at home. The woman wants to divorce her husband, but her husband doesn't agree to divorce. The woman goes out shopping, and the sad and angry husband stays at home. After that, a traveling salesman knocks on the door. He has a bag with a glass jar in it. There are small tropical fruits in the jar. The married man says: "You can't sell me anything!". The salesman asks the married man, "Why are you angry?". Married man says "My bad mood...". He invites the salesman into the house for a drink. The two men talk for a few hours, they joke. The married man says with a laugh, "You can't never sell these berries :-)".
After that:

 The salesman thanks him for the drink and gives him free fruit. The married man eats the fruits, and suddenly falls to the ground entering the crisis.
 The film ends. It turns out that his wife and the salesman have made plans to kill him.

Additional details:

It was a movie, not a show. I was watching a low-budget films on television every night.
Release date may be 1995 to 2006.
I think the husband looks like actor Jared Harris.


Sounds like a Married with Children episode :p

I wish I knew what this movie was, so I could edit the question to make it easier to understand^^ (As it stands now, I'm not sure what some of the sentences mean, there is ambiguity due to grammatical errors - I could guess, but not know) ...But, alas, I haven't seen this movie

Sorry for the grammar. I have used online translation.

Doesn't ring a bell and unfortunately all I could find was another person looking for it who got a joke reply. Do you remember the actors or what the characters looked like, by any chance? And is it possible it was an episode and not a movie?

Yes it is a movie.
I was watching a low-budget films on television every night.
Release date may 1995 to 2006.
I think he(husband) looks like this actor: http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/residentevil/images/c/c4/Charles_Asford.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130504041807
I wrote on this question of the Turkish website. (4 years ago)
I guess, my question another member was copied:https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130114041215AATIzLT

Googling "movie poison husband berries" turns up a movie where Halle Berry's character is accused of poisoning her husband!

@Malvolio what keeps you from writing down the name of that movie?

@Malvolio Google might have interpreted berries as typo from the name Berry...

@Marzipanherz -- not correcting a typo, it was a process called stemming.  The movie, FWIW, was The Rich Man's Wife.

@pori Can you add any more detail that might help?

@natural  The house is a single-storey detached house. The room where they chatted was in American kitchen style like this picture:
http://www.ineoteric.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/inspiration-design-american-kitchen-style-american-kitchen-style-american-style-kitchen-table-american-style-kitchen-accessories-american-style-kitchen-ideas-american-style-kitchen.jpg
Sorry I don't have more details to give.

That's sound similar to 1944 Double Indemnity so maybe it's some kind of TV-only remake or "inspired by".

I couldn't find any matching Jared Harris movie, but this awful "Double Indemnity" remake 1973 for TV could be it.
Why?

There not many variants of the original Billy Wilder "Double Indemnity" story. This is the only one long form, which stayed true to its limited theatrical form. There are many excerpts of Double Indemnity shorts on vimeo or youtube as short student or amateur projects.
It is really bad.
Richard Crenna resembles Jared Harris somewhat.

BTW: The Ashley Judd variant "Double Jeopardy" is much better.

Thanks for your reply but it's not the movie I was talking about.

No, that movie doesn't include berries, it includes shooting people with a handgun.

Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Indemnity_(film)
